# Qt6 with CLion: Errors while reading XML File in qrc with QXmlStreamReader and QFile: "QIODevice::Device not open"

Tags: c++, cmake, qt6

I'm writing an Syntax Highlighter with Qt6 CMake.
When I using QFile and QXmlStreamReader to read and parsing my Keyword Lists (a XML File) will show these errors:

```
Failed to open XML file
Path: ":/config/Configuration/RCodeEditor/KeywordList/cppKeywords.xml"
QIODevice::read (QFile, ":\config\Configuration\RCodeEditor\KeywordList\cppKeywords.xml"): device not open
XML parsing error: "Premature end of document."
```

And the related function is:

```
QStringList readKeywords(const QString &filePath) {
            QStringList names;

            QFile file(filePath);
//            if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
//                qDebug() << "Value of File Path" << filePath;
//                qDebug() << "Failed to open XML file：" << file.errorString();
//                return names;
//            }
            qDebug() << "Path:" << filePath;
            QXmlStreamReader xmlReader(&file);

            while (!xmlReader.atEnd() && !xmlReader.hasError()) {
                QXmlStreamReader::TokenType token = xmlReader.readNext();

                if (token == QXmlStreamReader::StartElement && xmlReader.name().toString() == "name") {
                    QString name = xmlReader.readElementText();
                    names.append(name);
                }
            }

            if (xmlReader.hasError()) {
                qWarning() << "XML parsing error:" << xmlReader.errorString();
            }

//            file.close();

            return names;
```

I'm trying to comment some 'meaningless' code blocks such as `file.close()` and others.
But it still meaningless for me.

The .qrc file is showned here:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/config">
        <file>Configuration/RCodeEditor/KeywordList/cppKeywords.xml</file>
        <file>Configuration/RCodeEditor/KeywordList/doxygenTags.xml</file>
    </qresource>
<RCC>
```

And the keyword list file is here, too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RetoCodeEditor>
    <KeywordList>
        <KContent>
            <keyword name = "alignas">
                <name>alignas</name>
            </keyword>
            <keyword name="alignof">
                <name>alignof</name>
            </keyword>
            <keyword name="and">
                <name>and</name>
            </keyword>
            <keyword name="and_eq">
                <name>and_eq</name>
            </keyword>
            <keyword name="asm">
                <name>asm</name>
            </keyword>
            <keyword name="auto">
                <name>auto</name>
            </keyword>
            <!-- And so many others -->
        </KContent>
    </KeywordList>
</RetoCodeEditor>
```

This is a very serious question that I have need to solved for my code editor.
Thank you very much!

Usage on the Constructor of Syntax Highlighter

```
 explicit RCFamilyHighlighter(QTextDocument *parent = nullptr) : QSyntaxHighlighter(parent) {
            initRegexp(); //Initialize Regular Expressions
            readAndSetStyle(":/config/Configuration/RCodeEditor/ColorThemes/Dracula.xml"); //Read and set default color theme

            QStringList keywordsL;
            keywordsL = readKeywords(":/config/Configuration/RCodeEditor/KeywordList/cppKeywords.xml");

//            QStringList doxygenTagsList;
//            doxygenTagsList = readKeywords(":/config/Configuration/RCodeEditor/KeywordList/doxygenTags.xml");

            for (const QString &pattern: keywordsL) {
                highlightingRules.append({QRegularExpression("\\b" + pattern + "\\b"), keywordFormat});
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file is open correctly? [Check your resources configuration](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html) and show some simple example where you can open your xml file and just `qDebug() << file.readLine();`?

Comment: Yes, I make sure I load the file correctly. Because I used the same code here and it works fine, but I don't know why it doesn't work. The `file.readLine()` function does not output anything here.